# Flutter "Add 2 App" Android integration with adjustments to generated .android

Tags: android, flutter

I'm working on an Android app with 3+ years of Kotlin development and want to gradually migrate it to Flutter feature-by-feature. I use [option B](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup#option-b---depend-on-the-modules-source-code) of the "add 2 app" integration where I depend on the module's source code. Features written Flutter are integrated into the native Android app with `FlutterActivity` or `FlutterFragment`. This worked great for the first feature however now I have an issue with migrating the second feature. The second feature requires the packages `camera` and `firebase_ml_vision`. Now the problem is that `camera` requires a min SDK of 21 but the generated Android code in `.android` sets the min SDK to 16. Additionally `firebase_ml_vision` requires initialization of Firebase which also needs to be added to `.android`. I'm thinking about adding `.android` to VCS and add the required changes however this is generated code. It gets removed when `flutter clean` is called and generated on `flutter pub get`. I would have to constantly adjust the generated code when Flutter changes/removes it :( `.android` only hosts the "skeleton" Android app which is started when the Flutter project is run from IDE (or command line). It is not the host app (the old, native app) where Firebase is already configured. However the `.android` app is used for quick development cycles. If I cannot use this anymore because of said limitations, I would always have to start the native Android app (host) and lose many benefits of Flutter like hot reload :( Has anyone come across the same problem?

**Update:**

In [this article](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/plugin-setup) they clearly state that `.android` should not be modified or added to VCS. They even mention the `camera` module as an example. However this does not work and can be reproduced with a few simple steps:

1. Create a new module: `flutter create --template=module --project-name example`
2. `cd example`
3. Add `camera` plugin to `pubspec.yaml`
4. `flutter pub get`
5. Now running `flutter build apk` results in the following error:

```
/Users/sven/Development/example/.android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [:camera] /Users/sven/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.5.8+11/android/build/intermediates/library_manifest/release/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
                or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
                or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.camera" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [:camera] /Users/sven/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.5.8+11/android/build/intermediates/library_manifest/release/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
                or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
                or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.camera" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the minSdk on the android app's `build.gradle(Module: app)` to 21 then regenerating it?

Comment: @Ferdinand Could you please explain what you mean by the "android app's build.gradle"? There is only a `.android` folder which is is removed and generated on `flutter clean && flutter pub get`.

Comment: You said you have 2 apps, the first one is written in kotlin and the 2nd in flutter, I mean you change it on the kotlin one and then regenerate the file.

Comment: @Ferdinand The Android app is already on minSDK 21 and was even before I added the Flutter module. This value has no impact on the generated `.android` folder since the Flutter module is not aware of the Android app. The Android app includes the module, not the other way around.

Comment: @SvenJacobs As per your screenshot you can use
  tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.camera" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Else try moving your all camara type code in Kotllin

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you are facing 2 issues/ questions:

1. **Minimum android sdk compatibility mismatch:** Probably requires some work by the flutter team for a proper fix (I expected the `flutter_module/build.gradle` to be more useful, but it wasn't (not the one in `build/` or `.android`), but as a workaround, some `:app` module `AndroidManifest.xml` changes using [uses-sdk](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element) will work:

```
<manifest ...>
   <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="29" android:minSdkVersion="21"
             tools:overrideLibrary="com.example.flutter_module, com.example.flutter_module.host"/>
    ...
</manifest>
```

(I set the default package name for the flutter module but you should replace both instances of `com.example.flutter_module` with your package name. (check your `build.gradle`s). What I do here is raise the minSDK for the 2 flutter modules that were added. The error message you got recommended lowering the minSDK for camera to 16, but this is not a good idea (the camera plugin developers set it to 21 probably because the APIs they use have minSDK 21, e.g. [camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary)).

---

2. **How to setup firebase/ dependencies config in build.gradle?** (i.e. `firebase_ml_vision` and `firebase` ['platform specific configuration'](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#6)): Change your main app's `app/build.gradle` and `AndroidManifest.xml` as per the instructions. This is what the [doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/plugin-setup#b-plugins-needing-project-edits) says:

> Perform those Android Gradle file edits on your outer, existing Android app rather than in your Flutter module.

---

Let me know if you need anymore help :)

Answer (score -3):

on `android/app/build.gradle` changing minSdkVersion to 21

Comment: There is no `android` folder, only `.android` and as I have stated above, this folder is removed and generated on `flutter clean && flutter pub get`.